# How can make a variable in inbound path at mule flow ?

Tags: java, mule, mule-esb

I want to read the value of **codes** in the servlet:inbound-endpoint

How can make the inbound receive different values for **codes**?

```
<flow name="VoucherAtmPage" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/voucher/atm/paycode/#[codes]"
        responseTimeout="210000" connector-ref="servletConnector" />

     <logger message="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.codes]" 
     level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>    
</flow>
```

I get this code while starting the server

```
Caused by: org.mule.api.endpoint.MalformedEndpointException: The endpoint 
"servlet:///voucher/atm/paycode/#[codes]" is malformed and cannot be parsed.
 If this is the name of a global endpoint, check the name is correct, that 
the endpoint exists, and that you are using the correct configuration (eg
the "ref" attribute).  Note that names on inbound and outbound endpoints
cannot be used to send or receive messages; use a named global endpoint
instead.. Only Outbound endpoints can be dynamic
   at org.mule.endpoint.AbstractEndpointBuilder.doBuildInboundEndpoint(AbstractEndpointBuilder.java:183)
   at org.mule.endpoint.AbstractEndpointBuilder.buildInboundEndpoint(AbstractEndpointBuilder.java:117)
   at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultEndpointFactory.getInboundEndpoint(DefaultEndpointFactory.java:83)
   at org.mule.config.spring.factories.InboundEndpointFactoryBean.doGetObject(InboundEndpointFactoryBean.java:49)
   at org.mule.config.spring.factories.AbstractEndpointFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractEndpointFactoryBean.java:43)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
   ... 49 more
```

Comment: I haven't used servelet:inbound-endpoint before, but have you tried the followingn for the path attribute: `/voucher/atm/paycode/{codes}`, or `/voucher/atm/paycode/:codes`?